# Java returning int from ArrayList<Integer> method

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, return

I've created a simple method that receives an `ArrayList<Integer>`, and then returns the average number as a `double`.

The code:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> tempGsnitt(ArrayList<Integer> temperatur){
        double sum = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i < temperatur.size(); i++)
            sum += temperatur.get(i);

        sum = sum/temperatur.size();

        return sum;
    }
```

But i'm getting an error that the method expects an `ArrayList` to return. So my question is; How can i return an `double` from an `ArrayList` method?

Comment: omg how could i be so stupid -.-

Answer (score 1):

Your return type is ArrayList, change to double.

```
public static double tempGsnitt(ArrayList<Integer> temperatur){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < temperatur.size(); i++)
        sum += temperatur.get(i);

    sum = sum/temperatur.size();

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change return type to `double`

```
public static double tempGsnitt(ArrayList<Integer> temperatur){}
```

Now your method looks like this

```
public static double tempGsnitt(ArrayList<Integer> temperatur){
  double sum = 0;
  for(int i = 1; i < temperatur.size(); i++) {
    sum += temperatur.get(i);
   }
  sum = sum/temperatur.size();
  return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you return a `double`?

```
public static double tempGsnitt(ArrayList<Integer> temperatur)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing input method parameters with return type.  Your method needs to take an ArrayList as an argument (input method) and it needs to return a double.

```
public static double tempGsnitt(ArrayList<Integer> temperatur){
    double sum = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < temperatur.size(); i++)
        sum += temperatur.get(i);

    sum = sum/temperatur.size();

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By returning a `double`:

```
public static double tempGsnitt(ArrayList<Integer> temperatur) {
    // Your code
}
```